# Function blocked (Python)

Tags: python, function, variables

A loop is blocking the function *changeStockPrice*, making variable *stockA* the default value (0.2). Please tell me the problem and how to fix it

I'm pretty sure *changeStockPrice* is the problem as:

> print(get_stocklist())

This gets the default value (0.2)

> print(round(abs(stockA + random.randint(-20, 20)/10),1))

This works perfectly (ranging from 0 to 2.2)

This is a simplified version of my code:

```py
import random
import time

stockA = 0.2

def get_stocklist():
  response = f"""Stocks：
  1E Discord {stockA}
  """
  return(response)

def changeStockPrice(stock):
  stock = round(abs(stock + random.randint(-20, 20)/10),1)
  return(stock)

def stockPriceChanger():
  global stockA

  while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    stockA = changeStockPrice(stockA)

print(get_stocklist())
print(round(abs(stockA + random.randint(-20, 20)/10),1))
```

Comment: you have a `while` loop with no break condition; that's the reason it is stuck there.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia how do I fix it? I need that to run indefinitely but I still need to run the other code

Comment: Look at the `threading` module or the `asyncio` module for two very different ways to run code in paralel

Answer (score 1):

```
def stockPriceChanger():
  global stockA

  while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    stockA = changeStockPrice(stockA)
    yield  #break (if you want to break it)
```

Here, the function goes in the **infinite Loop**. To avoid this situation you must **break** the while loop or put some condition to break it.

Answer (score 0):

Put the print statement inside the while loop.